# Licensing solutions compatible with e-junkie?

Tags: c#, .net, license-key, serial-number, piracy-prevention

I need a licensing solution. As it stands I've rolled my own partial key verification solution but obviously not being a cryptography expert or possessing a budget or a team to afford more than myself (I program solo for now) it's not perfect. It doesn't prevent people on the same network from using multiple copies of the same key (sharing amongst office workers) and it doesn't do any online activation at all.

I'm not looking for fort knox. I hate licensing as much as the next guy. I just want to keep honest people honest and stop people from casually sharing keys in environments where my software will be used most (in an office).

The problem isn't finding a licensing solution itself. There are 10s of solutions available to me. However, I am deciding to go with e-junkie as my distributor because I can't afford to maintain the security of a download server and I don't have the time to deal with setting up payment gateways. I never thought being an indie developer would be so hard.

The problem with e-junkie is they only support Armadillo/SoftwarePassport directly and they also support via POST using your own online key generator.

I have yet to find a paid solution that I can install on a linux web server (using PHP for example), generate a key based on POST data, and return it to e-junkie to be sent to the user. This is what prompted me to roll my own solution. I've already written both the C# and the PHP interfaces.

This leads me to my question. What licensing solutions (preferrably cheap) are available to me if I choose to use e-junkie as my distributor? Are there other distributors that offer licensing solutions for .NET/C# software as well as distribution on a revenue sharing basis (like Regnow)? I'm pretty new to this and would appreciate any of the advice I could get.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to ask for recommendations for other software/services/APIs.  We are here to answer questions about specific *programming* questions.  We are not here to help you find and recommend services/software offerred by 3rd parties that would help satisfy a particular need of yours.